# What is causing my "unrecognized selector" exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, exception, unrecognized-selector

I am independently going through the Programming iOS 7 course on iTunes U from Stanford, and therefore now that I have a question and I can't ask the teacher, I'm hoping someone here can help me out.  Ideally by telling me how to track down this type of problem, but I'm also posting my entire project at http://talix.homeip.net/2014/Matchismo.zip (since I don't think I can usefully post the UI for you to debug it in this post like normal text code), so just telling me where specifically the problem is would be very much appreciated as well!  I'm in the middle of assignment 3 for anyone who has taken the same course.

I've got a very basic card matching game that can play with playing cards or "Set".  The playing card tab works great.  The Set tab crashes with an uncaught exception (copied below) as soon as I press the New Game button or click on a card (which results in starting a new game).  I have put a breakpoint in my code so that I catch the New Game action, and stepped through all of the resulting code.  It all seems to work fine when I am stepping through my code.  When I reach the end of the last of my functions that get called as a result of the action, and then I press Continue in XCode, that's when it crashes.  Given that fact, I'm not sure how to trace what exactly is causing the problem.

Another question: Is it useful to post the entire call stack from the exception text, or are the top couple lines the only really useful ones (for beginners like me at least)?  I think I see that the unrecognized selector in question is [__NSCFConstantString _isDefaultFace]:, but I don't know where that would be getting called as part of what I'm assuming is UI code behind the types of classes I use (UILabel, etc.).

Here is the whole exception text just in case:

```
2014-09-28 18:45:54.337 Matchismo[17292:2714082] -[__NSCFConstantString _isDefaultFace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc721c
2014-09-28 18:45:54.346 Matchismo[17292:2714082] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _isDefaultFace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc721c'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01cfddf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01987a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01d05a75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01c4e9c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01c4e58e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIFoundation                        0x0355a1a9 -[NSMutableAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedStringKitAdditions) fixFontAttributeInRange:] + 2593
    6   UIFoundation                        0x035596b6 -[NSMutableAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedStringKitAdditions) fixAttributesInRange:] + 132
    7   UIFoundation                        0x0356b371 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 6661
    8   UIFoundation                        0x03571c00 -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 1311
    9   UIKit                               0x0068fd5e -[UIButton _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 825
    10  UIKit                               0x00ae4be6 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) intrinsicContentSize] + 51
    11  UIKit                               0x00ae51e5 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 36
    12  UIKit                               0x00ae4f16 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 505
    13  UIKit                               0x00aed1aa -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 185
    14  UIKit                               0x0068f7e1 -[UIButton updateConstraints] + 3366
    15  UIKit                               0x00aec614 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 259
    16  UIKit                               0x00aec861 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 127
    17  UIKit                               0x00aec7dc __UIViewRecursionHelper + 41
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01bf29b9 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    19  UIKit                               0x00aec5af -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 158
    20  UIKit                               0x00aec894 __125-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:]_block_invoke + 43
    21  Foundation                          0x015766f7 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 150
    22  Foundation                          0x01579c4f -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    23  UIKit                               0x00aec3fb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
    24  UIKit                               0x00aec861 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 127
    25  UIKit                               0x00aecdf6 __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 105
    26  Foundation                          0x015766f7 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 150
    27  Foundation                          0x01579c4f -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    28  UIKit                               0x00aec3fb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
    29  UIKit                               0x00aeca4c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 248
    30  UIKit                               0x00aed27e -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 170
    31  UIKit                               0x003eec9e -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 120
    32  UIKit                               0x003eef9c -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 57
    33  UIKit                               0x003fc9c0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608
    34  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0199d771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    35  QuartzCore                          0x0462227f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
    36  QuartzCore                          0x04616105 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397
    37  QuartzCore                          0x04615f60 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    38  QuartzCore                          0x04574676 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
    39  QuartzCore                          0x04575a3c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
    40  QuartzCore                          0x0463b789 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    41  UIKit                               0x0036e0d3 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2296
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x01c217bf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x01c172cd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x01c16828 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x01c161ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x01c15fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    47  GraphicsServices                    0x0415024f GSEventRunModal + 192
    48  GraphicsServices                    0x0415008c GSEventRun + 104
    49  UIKit                               0x00371e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    50  Matchismo                           0x000bd80d main + 141
    51  libdyld.dylib                       0x022d0ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \[NSTextStorage setAttributedString\] crash with NSMutableAttributedString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153810/why-does-nstextstorage-setattributedstring-crash-with-nsmutableattributedstrin)

Comment: You have to pass a font object, not the font name.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are of course correct!  Once you pointed out the offending line, I was able to not only fix it but understand exactly why it needed fixing.

Comment: I would say not a duplicate, because the primary question remains: why didn't my code crash when I stepped over it in debug mode?  If it had done that and therefore pointed out which line was the issue, I probably would have been able to figure it out myself without bothering you fine folks.  I will try to remember to search this site specifically with the unrecognized selector text next time, though, rather than just "unrecognized selector", which I did try and of course it wasn't very helpful.  ;-)

Comment: Also, thanks to Paul Griffiths - I should have thought to put that long exception text in a code block, and will try to do so in the future.

Comment: Your code didn't crash when you stepped over it because you didn't step over it.  **As can be seen from the stack trace**, the crash is occurring in the "draw" logic that is executed automatically by the system, not in "your" code.  When "draw" happens (or even whether it happens) is not tied to where you are with the debugger in your own logic.

Comment: (FWIW, the dupe above was the *very first* "hit" that Google got for "_isDefaultFace".)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense @HotLicks, thank you, even if it is disappointing from an ease of debugging point of view.  I was thinking it was redrawing when I stepped over the line that set the button text.  As I mentioned, I'm very new to all of this, so even though I read over the stack trace, I was not able to interpret it very well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like I can't mark Hot Licks's comment as an answer to give reputation and mark it as the accepted answer, so I will put my own "answer" down here - but he should get the credit!  :-)

The problem was I was passing an NSString as the NSFontAttributeName of an NSAttributedString, rather than an UIFont object.  Here is the old offending code:

```
return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,
                                                                    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : color,
                                                                    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : strokeWidth,
                                                                    NSFontAttributeName : @"System 12.0"}];
```

And here is the corrected code:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,
                                                                    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : color,
                                                                    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : strokeWidth,
                                                                    NSFontAttributeName : font}];
```

In retrospect, an obvious mistake, but aren't they always in hindsight?    This is my first time using NSAttributedString, so hopefully I won't make the same mistake again in the future.  Thanks again, Hot Licks!

My more long-term and serious question remains: why didn't this code crash when I stepped over it in the debugger, so that I would know what line to focus on?

Comment: It didn't crash when you stepped over it because `initWithString` did not rigorously test its parameters, but merely stored the values.  This was "facilitated" by the fact that the parameters were passed as a "attributes" dictionary vs individual parameters (which would have produced a compiler warning message).  Objective-C and its libraries are not particularly rigorous about checking parameters, compared to, say, Java.